# 動的な変数の発生について

Tags: python

pythonで質問です。
df1, df2, df3, ..., dfnというn個のデータフレーム型の変数を発生させたいと考えております。

こちらどのようにコードを書くか、ご教示いただくことはできないでしょうか。

どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 何が判らないのですか？　pythonのコードを書いたことはありますか？

Answer (score 0):

あまり書いたことはありません。
以下のようなものを書いてみたのですが、print(df100)と最後に打っても何も出てきませんでした。

import pandas as pd
for i in range (1,131):
 dfi = pd.DataFrame()
print(df100)